# joining string and long in python

Tags: python

I want to join the foll:

```
col = ('NS', 2013L)
```

to get:

```
'NS_2013'
```

I am doing this:

```
'_'.join(str(col)), and I get this: "(_'_N_S_'_,_ _2_0_1_3_L_)"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax).

```
>>> col = ('NS', 2013L)
>>> '{}_{}'.format(col[0], col[1])
'NS_2013'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> col = ('NS', 2013L)
>>> col
('NS', 2013L)
>>> '%s_%d' % col
'NS_2013'
```

Answer (score 1):

The mistake you are making is in applying the `str` invocation to the entire `col` tuple rather than the elements of `col`:

```
col = ('NS', 2013L)
'_'.join(str(element) for element in col)
```

yields:

```
'NS_2013"
```

which I believe is what you are after.